# Set up host file using port

Tags: apache

I want to setup my host file to

**127.0.0.2:5050 domain2.com**  => this is a local domain

when a type in my browser domain2.com, this return me : HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

i use this in apache

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.9:5050>

    ServerAdmin info@domain2.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/My_Dir/LOOP/WebEnginer-2011/domain2_Dir/"
    ServerName domain2.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com
    ErrorLog "c:/wamp/xxxx/xxxx.log"
    CustomLog "c:/wamp/xxxx/xxxx.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.9:5050>

    ServerAdmin info@domain2.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/My_Dir/LOOP/WebEnginer-2011/domain2_Dir/admin_Dir/"
    ServerName admin.domain2.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
    ServerAlias www.admin.domain2.com
    ErrorLog "c:/wamp/xxxx/xxxx.log"
    CustomLog "c:/wamp/xxxx/xxxx.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

but when i type **127.0.0.2:5050** i can see a web page. I want to use subdomain like admin.domain2.com

i can't use port 80 because IIS use that port.

How can i set up my host file to listen **domain2.com**?

Comment: Do not forget to alter the Listen instruction in apache. You should have a `127.0.0.9:5050` or `*:5050` and a related `NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.9:5050` `NameVirtualHost *:5050` in main configuation

Answer (score 3):

That won't work since the hosts file only serves the purpose of mapping a hostname to an IP-address. The port number of a service is a different concept and is not handled by the "hosts" file nor the DNS-System. In Short: you can't supply a port number in the "hosts" file.

If your Webserver works on another port, you have to supply that information in the URL: http://domain2.com:5050.

The only other solution is to configure your Webservers to listen on a specific IP so that they don't interfere with each other. For example the IIS could listen on 127.0.0.1 and the Apache on 127.0.0.2 (the way you have already configured it).

[There's a HOWTO for achieving that with the IIS](http://www.wiredred.com/web-conferencing-manual/configureiistouseoneipad.htm). I'm not sure if that works for 127.0.0.x-IP's but I think it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

It might be:

- Your DNS resolver not resolving that properly
- Some Apache webserver misconfiguration

Try this to get more information about that:

1. What if you ping domain2.com?
2. Also, try what happens if you put something like `domain2.local` in your hosts file. It might be some windows security c** disallowing you to overwrite the ip of an existing domain.
3. Why didn't you use 127.0.0.1? That should be fine, however
4. Make sure you have a properly configured VirtualHost that accepts requests to "domain2.com", or you just have a default virtualhost.

**EDIT**
What did you actually add to hosts file? The correct syntax would be:

```
127.0.0.2     domain2.com
```

Comment: i try this 127.0.0.2     domain2.com but don't work. I remove :5050 to 127.0.0.2, still not working.

Comment: What if you use: `127.0.0.1    domain2.local` and then `ping domain2.local` ?

Comment: ..I just realized that, as vstm says, you didn't add the port number to the URL (that is, you must use http://domain2.com:5050 instead of http://domain2.com). Maybe the best solution if you want to type just http://domain2.com is to configure IIS to listen only on 127.0.0.1 and apache to listen only on 127.0.0.2