# set Hosts windows 7 for port 8080 wamp server

Tags: apache, localhost, wampserver

wampserver is working perfectly, I have to enter to access localhost:8080 I tried to modify the hosts file in the directory

```
\windows\system32\drivers\etc
```

and put the line

```
127.0.0.1:8080 localhost
```

but it is not working, if not how to do it with that file is there another solution?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787483/set-up-host-file-using-port - the first answer isn't accepted, but it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do 127.0.0.1:8080 localhost because you can not put ports in hosts  file, you should only put IP addresses...

Answer (score -1):

Change the part in httpd.conf where it says "Listen 80" to "Listen 8080" . It should work.